# React Component not showing on matched Route (react-router-dom)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Hey everyone I dont know whats going on. 
I have the following routes:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/patient/:id/" component={PatientWrapper} />
      <Route path="/patient/:id/patient_profile/admission_form" component={PatientAdmission} />
      <Route path="/patient/:id/patient_profile/discharge_form" component={PatientDischarge} />
      <Route path="/patient/:id/patient_profile/encounter_details" component={PatientEncounterDetails} />
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Only **Route with path="/"** and **Route with path="/patient/:id"** are the ones working, the other 3 routes are just not showing the component that corresponds to the path.

This is how I access to the Route. I have a Header Component with the proper links on it. See below

```
<ul className="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
    <li><Link to={"/patient/" + this.props.id +"/patient_profile/admission_form"} id="admission-link" >Admission</Link></li>
     <li><Link to={"/patient/" + this.props.id +"/patient_profile/discharge_form"} id="discharge-link">Discharge</Link></li>
     <li className="divider"></li>
     <li><Link to={"/patient/" + this.props.id +"/patient_profile/encounter_details"} id="encounter-details">Encounter Details</Link></li>
</ul>
```

In the Header component I **import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';** and in the file where I declare the routes I **import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A loose guess: try reordering the first patient route to underneath the ones with more complex paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is you are not using [`exact`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) prop for your parent routes. By default, Route doesn't do an exact match. As an example for path `/`, both `/` and `/patient` are considered as matches. So even in your case, `/patient/:id/` Route matches for all other routes path which starts from `/patient/:id/`. Since Switch only renders the first match, it always renders PatientWrapper even for other paths like `/patient/:id/patient_profile/admission_form`.

Using `exact` prop as follows you can explicitly instruct Route to match exactly.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path="/patient/:id/" exact component={PatientWrapper} />
      <Route path="/patient/:id/patient_profile/admission_form" component={PatientAdmission} />
      <Route path="/patient/:id/patient_profile/discharge_form" component={PatientDischarge} />
      <Route path="/patient/:id/patient_profile/encounter_details" component={PatientEncounterDetails} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the answer with a better explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, there is alot I still need to learn

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you wrap routes in  when you render them:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
       <Route path="/patient/:id/" component={PatientWrapper} />
      <Route path="/patient/:id/patient_profile/admission_form" component={PatientAdmission} />
      <Route path="/patient/:id/patient_profile/discharge_form" component={PatientDischarge} />
      <Route path="/patient/:id/patient_profile/encounter_details" component={PatientEncounterDetails} />
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```